# how to get picture form .docx in android studio using Apache poi

Tags: android, apache-poi

```
XWPFPictureData pictureData = picture.getPictureData();
byte[] bytepic = pictureData.getData();
BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytepic));

if(imag != null){              
    ImageIO.write(imag, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Documents\\Word Files\\question"+ q +".png"));
}else {

}
```

it works in java but not in android studio.
I want to get the picture in .png or jpg or any other format in android studio using the apache poi

If there is any way?

Comment: How is it not working in Android Studio? Without explaining what's going wrong, it's hard for us to help... Explain exactly what error you get, where, what isn't as expected etc